# 'chcp' function not working when run in a Scheduled Task

Tags: powershell, character-encoding, scheduled-tasks

I have a PowerShell function written that looks for scheduled tasks by name. Like so.

```
$null = chcp 1252
schtasks /query /v /fo csv | Where-Object { $_.TaskName -like $ScheduledTaskName }
```

It works perfectly when I run the function myself, but it does not work when run in a scheduled task.

The problem is with character encoding. Some scheduled task names have characters like ä and ö in them. For some reason chcp does not work as intended when ran in a scheduled task.

To make sure `chcp` is executed I added two lines of

```
chcp | Out-File $filePath -Append
```

And sure, `chcp` is changed from `850` to `1252` in the function. Then I made the function to output results of `schtasks` query into a file.

```
$tasks = schtasks /query /v /fo csv | ConvertFrom-Csv
$tasks | Out-File $filePath -Encoding utf8
```

And there I can see that character encoding is not correct.

`$OutputEncoding` is set to `1252` as well by default.

How the heck do I fix the character encoding issue in scheduled task?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.  Why aren't using just UTF16 (unicode) or UTF8.  What is the input?  Why you are trying to force encoding different than unicode?

Comment: Huh? Okay. schtasks is a native applicatiion, not a PowerShell cmdlet. 1252 is the encoding that works for characters like ö and ä with schtasks. UTF8 encoding (65001) does not. And neither does 850 which is what Windows defaults to when correct country is selected in regional settings.

Comment: so why don't use use Unicode (alias for UTF16) in MS world?

Comment: I am sorry what? What does MS Word have anything to do with this?

Comment: LOL, World **not** Word!   I'm talking about `Out-File -Encoding unicode` which is UTF16.

Comment: Out-File is simply a debugging step to see output of schtasks. It is not relevant to the problem at hand and is not included in the function under normal conditions. Please understand that the function works as intended when it is run normally by user, but not when it is run by scheduled task.

Comment: Yes, I understand that (that was just an example).  My point is why don't you try to circumvent the issue all together by using the Unicode encoding everywhere.  Is there a reason for that

Comment: Yes there is. Neither 65001 (UTF8) nor 10000 (UTF16) encodes characters like ö and ä correctly, including when run by user. Then there is the issue that Unicode (UTF16) requires font that supports it, at least Windows Server 2008 R2 still defaults to raster font.

Comment: I see.  So the issue is with the source system which does not produce correctly the Unicode characters?  There should not be any big issues with characters ö and ä in Unicode.   Actually, it would be nice to know your workflow.

Comment: Don't use `schtasks.exe`. There are other programmatic ways of retrieving scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally solved this.

```
$Encoding = 1252
try {
    [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding($Encoding)
}
catch {
    Write-Warning 'Console OutputEncoding is not settable on older versions of PowerShell ISE.'
}
$OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding($Encoding)
$null = chcp $Encoding
```

Now schtasks outputs correctly.